# pass array from NSViewController to NSView in Objective C Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, nsviewcontroller

Im making a program to draw the chart (which i keep in NSView class). However action & data I want to pass from NSViewController. So could you help me how to do it. I did try as bellow code however it doesn't work.

```
@implementation PlottingChart
@synthesize plotChartData;
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    [self drawChartGrid:plotChartData];
}

-(void)drawChartGrid:(NSMutableArray *)ChartData
{
     //Drawing code here
}
```

```
@interface PlottingChart : NSView
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray     *plotChartData;
    -(void)drawChartGrid:(NSMutableArray *)ChartData;
@end
```

```
#import "PlottingChart.h"

@interface ViewController :NSViewController<NSTableViewDataSource,NSTableViewDelegate>
{
    PlottingChart *boxPlotChart;
}
```

```
- (IBAction)btnStart:(id)sender {
    //trial draw chart
    NSDictionary *dict1 = @{@"plot_Q1":@"180",@"plot_Q3": @"220", @"plot_Max":@"250", @"plot_Min":@"150", @"plot_Median":@"200"};
    NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"plot_Q1":@"190",@"plot_Q3": @"230", @"plot_Max":@"280", @"plot_Min":@"160", @"plot_Median":@"210"};

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:dict1,dict2, nil];

    boxPlotChart.plotChartData = array;
    [boxPlotChart drawChartGrid:array];
    boxPlotChart = [[PlottingChart alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, -50, 850, 360) ]; // x,y lenght,height

    [self.view addSubview:boxPlotChart];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are using `boxPlotChart` with `boxPlotChart.plotChartData = array;` and `[boxPlotChart drawChartGrid:array];` and after that creating a new `PlottingChart` that will have no data?

Comment: I just try to pass array from ViewController to PlottingChart View. however seem it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you have these two lines `boxPlotChart.plotChartData = array;
[boxPlotChart drawChartGrid:array];` they seem redundant, you are setting the array and then drawing with argument of the same array, you either add the array to the property `boxPlotChart.plotChartData = array`  and then draw - where you already have the array in the `plotChartData` property

Comment: I did try 3 case one is only: boxPlotChart.plotChartData = array ; other one only: [boxPlotChart drawChartGrid:array]; and final one is both. Seem 3 way can't pass array to the boxPlotChart. During debug I also didn't see any array pass through boxPlotChart. do you have any suggestion,

Comment: Can you please update code in `btnStart` method to what you have currently, since what you had before makes no sense because of the order things are called

Comment: What's your mean update code in btnStart. What code I need to change ?

Comment: What you currently have does not make sense, you are using boxPlotChart and then at the end you allocinit it? Its like first eat pizza and then afterward make it...you have to make it first then use it

Comment: Turn this: 
`boxPlotChart.plotChartData = array;`
`[boxPlotChart drawChartGrid:array];`
`boxPlotChart = [[PlottingChart alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, -50, 850, 360) ]; // x,y lenght,height`
Into:
`boxPlotChart = [[PlottingChart alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, -50, 850, 360) ]; // x,y lenght,height`
`boxPlotChart.plotChartData = array;`
`[boxPlotChart drawChartGrid:array];`

Comment: Seem it still not work. I follow you advice to change code. I think because of after "boxPlotChart = [[PlottingChart alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, -50, 850, 360) ];" boxPlotChart already execute [self drawChartGrid:plotChartData]

Comment: I try to remove [self drawChartGrid:plotChartData] from - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    [self drawChartGrid:plotChartData];
}
 seem it not work too.

Comment: I found the solution tks Ladislav

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution.

Add initWithFrame method into NSView.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame dataArray:(NSMutableArray *)dtArray;
 {
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   self.plotChartData = dtArray;
   return self;
  }
```

And initial this one in NSViewController.

```
boxPlotChart = [[PlottingChart alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, -50, 850, 360) dataArray:array ];
```

Comment: It’s much better to use protocols and delegation. There is no need to pass the date to the view like its done in your solution. NSTableView other controls do it the same way. (MVC !!!)